# Two uses of "which" in the same sentence

Tags: which-that

I would like to ask whether I can use "which" twice in the following sentence:

> We are so (so!) excited for our big day which is just around the corner and which would be meaningless without you!

Comment: No, you must never repeat the same word again anywhere else in a sentence if thou hast already written it earlier, doncha know?

Comment: @tchrist English Language and Yousage?

Answer (score -2):

As a conjunction has been used, there is nothing wrong with the sentence in terms of the repeated use of *which*.

Stylistically, you probably want to put a comma before each instance of *which*:

> We are so (so!) excited for our big day, which is just around the corner, and which would be meaningless without you!

---

At least in US English (but not UK English), if the information is restrictive (if you don't use a comma), you normally use *that* rather than *which*. Doing so here would make the sentence look like this:

> We are so (so!) excited for our big day that is just around the corner and that would be meaningless without you!

However, aside from the issue of *which* or *that*, with or without commas, the repetition of the word itself is fine.